# Word for someone who blindly follows a religion or government

Tags: single-word-requests

What word describes a person who blindly (unquestioningly) follows a government or religion? I am looking for a specific word that I came across recently but have since forgotten what is was and where I found it.  It is similar to zealot in definition but it is not zealot or any of the synonyms typically presented in a thesaurus.  I believe the definition more emphasized the unquestioning aspect rather than the fanaticism.

Comment: I don't know of any questioning zealot.

Comment: @Kris: +1 for the good laugh (definitions aside).

Comment: A word for a person ... you emphasize not the person. Can you clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: @Anybody: seems there is confusion on the exact requirement in your question (see below). Second the request for clarity - I think the question title and the body do not 100% align.

Comment: Can Anybody answer? Does Anybody know?

Comment: "True believer" is probably pretty close.  Or perhaps "ideologue".

Comment: @JimReynolds Anybody is the asker, incidentally.

Comment: A "true believer" can still question things. Just the outcome will still be the same.

Answer (score 6):

One obvious contender is [*fanatic,*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fanatic) and the related adjective *fanatical:*

> NOUN
>
> 1 A person filled with excessive and single-minded zeal, especially for an extreme religious or political cause.
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *Much to the chagrin of my room-mates, come election time I will roam around extolling the necessity of voting with the zeal of a religious fanatic.*
>
> *The extreme right wing religious fanatics truly scare me beyond belief.*
>
> *Wesley's eyes glint with a religious fanatic's zeal.*

(Definition and examples from Oxforddictionaries.com)

You could also describe such a person as a **slavish adherent / slavish supporter [of something].**

Comment: This does not answer the question. "fanatic" is a synonym for "zealot", and like "zealot", does not include 'unquestioning' in its definition.

Comment: @ZayneSHalsall - I disagree. If your zeal is both excessive and single-minded, the extent to which you are questioning your devotion must necessarily be minimal.

Comment: It's hard to say that the answer won't help the OP, but technically, Zayne is right. Someone who's fanatical (probably) can't be questioning (critical), but would not describe a person who unquestionably but unenthusiastically follows a government or religion. O.o

Comment: @JimReynolds - If you follow a government or religion *unenthusiastically*, then you can't be described as a *fanatic* even if you also follow it *unquestioningly* (which I assume is the word you *meant* to use).

Comment: @ ErikKowal The OP did not, (maybe) want to include enthusiasm as central to the construct. If the OP wants a word for one who does or tends to unquestioningly (and that's fixed, thanks) but not zealously follow, then fanatical cannot work. Also, he wants a word that describes a person, so it cannot be a noun, but must be an adjective. "Uncritical" is part of at least one dictionary definition of fanatic/fanatical: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fanatical. But the definition of fanatical is vitally related to intensity, and the OP (maybe) wants a word that means an uncritical follower.

Comment: @JimReynolds - Well, I suppose we'll have to see if the OP clarifies what the focus of their question actually is and what part of speech they are after. Only then will there be a possibility of resolving the points at issue.

Comment: [Fanatic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fanatic?searchDictCode=all) -> [religious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/religious?searchDictCode=all) -> [faith](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/faith) -> [trust](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trust): "Acceptance of the truth of a statement without evidence or investigation". Sounds unquestioning to me.

Answer (score 4):

I think you might have been looking for "ideologue."

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ideologue
Definition of ideologue
1:  an impractical idealist :  theorist
2:  an often blindly partisan advocate or adherent of a particular ideology

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you Carol!

Answer (score 2):

The word "**devotee**" is suggestive of unwavering (and perhaps quasi-religious) personal commitment.

Answer (score 2):

**acolyte** (originally one who assists a priest, but later a follower)

MW lists synonyms as:

follower, adherent, convert, disciple, epigone, liege man, partisan (also partizan), pupil, votarist, votary

Answer (score 1):

APPARATCHIK

A word I have not heard in many years but that I believe applies to many in our current political climate (garnered from Merriam-Webster online)  :

In the context of the definition of "apparatchik" (a term English speakers borrowed from Russian), "apparat" essentially means "party machine." An "apparatchik," therefore, is a cog in the system of the Communist Party. The term is not an especially flattering one, and its negative connotations reflect the perception that some Communists were obedient drones in the great Party machine. In current use, however, a person doesn't have to be a member of the Communist Party to be called an "apparatchik"; he or she just has to be someone who mindlessly follows orders in an organization or bureaucracy.

Comment: I believe you are wrong about the "current use". A person must be a member of the "apparat" (the ruling party or other organs of government) to be considered an apparatchik.

Comment: This came verbatim from Merriam-Webster so if someone is wrong it is Merriam-Webster but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

A sheep.

[2.
a. A person regarded as timid, weak, or submissive.
b. One who is easily swayed or led.](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=sheep&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)

But in my experience, it's rarely used as in *He/she is a sheep.* It seems more common to use as a plural noun (maybe because sheep tend to follow as a flock).  It also seems to be used in simile forms: *follow/obey like sheep.*

Comment: This does not answer the question. "sheep", like "zealot", neither means nor includes 'unquestioning' in its definition.

Comment: Right. A one-word adjective naming the attribute of unquestionably following a government or religion.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading OP (very possible, perhaps clarity in question will help), "sheep" may match 'unquestioning' but does not match 'zealot' as well, which was the question.

Comment: There is the neologism "sheeple" which fits the OP's requirements moderately well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "unquestioning" as the adjective you seek.

"Zealous" is associated more with eagerness than blind faith (and "blindly faithful" is an appropriate adjectival phrase), but could still work; "convicted" is perhaps a little archaic for modern use, but I'll note it anyway.

Bear in mind, though, that the society that originated these words viewed faith in authority - divine or secular - as an unequivocal good.

Comment: zealot would be the noun

Answer (score 0):

An **unconditional** believer in the Fed's interest rate policy would have ([dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unconditional)) absolute, not limited by conditions, faith in [Dr. Yellens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chair_of_the_Federal_Reserve) manipulations of the [federal funds rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_funds_rate).

Answer (score 0):

[Dogmatic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dogmatic):

> Inclined to lay down principles as undeniably true

I believe dogmatic is the word you are looking for.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Answer (score -1):

Bigot. (one obstinately and irrationally, often intolerantly, devoted to his own church, party, belief, or opinion. - Webster)

Two instances from Google Books:
[1](https://books.google.com/books?id=USBnOM1Qcl0C&pg=PA26&dq=bigot&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IE2NVL6gNIXyUqing5gL&ved=0CEgQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=bigot&f=false)
[2](https://books.google.com/books?id=V89EClrK9X4C&pg=PA51&dq=bigot&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RE2NVPGnHoP5Us33gZAH&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=bigot&f=false)

Comment: *Bigots* may tend to follow unquestioningly, but I think the defining characteristic of the term has more to do with attitudes that hold outsiders or others as inferior.

Comment: Zealot means negative, when we describe it to "unquestioning" its negative meaning increases. A sheep is not a zealot necessarily, because he/she is not impassioned eagerness especially in favor of a person or a cause usually; a sheep is more a passive person than a fanatic person.

Comment: A sheep follows the rules because he/she has to do it or he/she is apathetic person. About a sheep i think there is a apathetic sense in him/her to authority.

Comment: @user64617: Your answer doesn't answer this question. "zealot"  neither implies nor includes unquestioning in its definition, therefore OP is looking for a **single word** that _does_ that (i.e. 'unquestioning' + 'zealot'). A "bigot" is not the same as a "zealot": former describes **intolerance** towards _non-partisan_ opinions/beliefs, latter **fervor/passion** towards _partisan_ opinions/beliefs. And "bigot", like "zealot", neither implies nor includes unquestioning in its definition.

Comment: "Zealot" and "bigot" both describe fervor/passion toward partisan opinions/beliefs. But "bigot" also describes intolerance towards non-partisan opinions/beliefs. A text what the words have used in them reflects being unquestioning or not.

Comment: @user64617: You are wrong, check the definitions - bigotry is aimed outwards, only. I don't understand your second sentence.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong. Second sentence: neither "zealot" nor "bigot" do not describe the state of "unquestioning" by themselves, but the text which they use in it reveals the state of "unquestioning" in them.

Comment: @user64617: yes, context always add meaning, but the OP asked for a word, not a phrase or "text" (which your attempted answer follows by providing a single word). So this point is also irrelevant unless the question changes.

Comment: What about "hardliner"?

Answer (score -1):

I think the word **idolatrous** pertains more specifically to the question at hand; with a specific definition in terms of unfettered and uncriticising devotion to something.

Answer (score -1):

Try myrmidon.  Defined by [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/myrmidon) as a follower who carries out orders without question, and [Oxford English Dictionaries on line](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/myrmidon)  adds, typically one who is unscrupulous.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage Matthew. I have edited your answer to include hyperlinks to your sources. Those links are usually needed.

Answer (score -2):

Confirmation bias is the term I learned from my brother-in-law. It described someone who blindly follows the beliefs of a group, such as a political party.

Answer (score -3):

I don't see **fascist** here, and I would think it deserves consideration. [The Elusive Definition of 'Fascist'](https://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2016/12/fascism-populism-presidential-election/510668/) is a pretty deep -- and interesting -- dive.

Comment: Fascism might be an unpalatable political view to most, but you've failed to demonstrate that fascists are any more blind or unquestioning than adherents of any other political view.

Comment: @Chappo To fail to do something requires an attempt to do it. I haven't made any such attempt. On that basis I disagree with you.

Comment: What you're therefore saying is that you haven't attempted to answer the question, since you've singled out one unique category of political adherent, possibly as a personal political comment. BTW, your linked article decries the very use of *fascist* that you're proposing.

Comment: To fail ***at** doing something* requires an attempt to do it.   To fail ***to** do something* requires no such attempt.

Comment: @Chappo "Possibly as a personal political comment" is a bit of a reach, although, of course, anything is possible. Your statement is possibly an attempt at a personal attack, for example. I didn't understand that I needed to demonstrate why I mentioned the word; perhaps this is an unspoken requirement of which I was unaware. My thought on mentioning the term is that fascism is characterized by authoritarian rule that doesn't brook opposition, and logic would therefore suggest that adherents of it are willing to follow an authoritarian ruler who doesn't brook opposition.

Comment: Bob, you might be unaware that our site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*; see [answer] for further guidance. You should explain what the linked article says in support of your suggested word. Also, "fascist" would be a **particular example** of the word the OP is looking for; however, the adherents of a religious cult would *also* be described by the word the OP is looking for, and they would probably not be fascists.

Comment: @Chappo Yes, I was unaware of that, and I appreciate the explanation. Thank you. And if the OP's "government *or* religion" is taken in the "logical operator" sense of "government *and* religion," which it of course it often is, then the word certainly doesn't apply. I suppose my IT background got me to assume that a word that describes one or the other might apply. Again, thanks for explaining, and I will be more careful with my answers here in future. (I spend a lot of time on the ELL site, which is a bit different as you say.)

Comment: @Scott You're quite right. Suppose we edit my comment with your suggested change. :)